# Find a basis and dimension of V

Tags: linear-algebra

When finding a basis for a vector space defined by $V = \{p(x) \in P_3(\Bbb R) \mid p(3)=0\text{ and }p(2)=0\}$, I started by showing $p(x) = (x-2)(x-3)q(x)$ where $q(x)\in P_1(\Bbb{R})$.
So, $p(2) = 8a+4b+2c+d = 0 $
And, $p(3) = 27a+9b+3c+d = 0$
I am wondering do I set these equal and solve for each independent variable a,b,c,d and with that answer is my basis?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have the solution. Every such p(x) is determined by the third root. This root is given by q(x). You are right that q(x) has degree 1. Since that is the only restriction, every polynomial in P$_1$ is allowed to be q(x). Thus V $\cong$ P$_1$. So the dimension of V is 2.

Alternatively, you can think of q(x) = ax + b, for any a,b $\in \mathbb{R}$. Since there are 2 degrees of freedom, dim V = 2.

Comment: Okay thanks I understand that so my basis can just be made of ax+b?

Comment: @ilovesports524 Not quite. V is made up of ax+b. To find a basis, you need a linearly independent set. Consider when a=1, b=0 (corresponding to q(x)=x) and a=0, b=1 (corresponding to q(x) = 1).

Answer (score 0):

Go for $$\{(x-2)(x-3), x(x-2)(x-3)\}$$ for your basis.

These two polynomials  will span your space and they are linearly independent.

Comment: Isn't this a multiple of eachother

Comment: That is OK. they are not scalar multiple of each other.